# Istio without Kubernetes

Tags: istio, servicemesh

I need to build service mesh since I have a big monolith and few (around 10 but will grow in number) microservices.

We don't use Kubernetes and we deploy all our service on linux as docker containers beside the monolith as it deployed as bare tomcat web server.

Can I Istio as service mesh on linux without Kubernetes? on "bare" Linux? of course there is no single machine that hosts to the above services but 3-5 machines

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you looked into consul?